# How can I get anchortags aligned properly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and trying to align my anchors so that they are at the bottom of the div on the lefts side. At the moment they are outside the div ie under it:

```
<div class="row vcenteritems itemsheight border">
   <div class="col-md-8 small">
        <!-- react-text: 144 -->Docos
        <!-- /react-text -->
        <!-- react-text: 145 -->channel package
        <!-- /react-text -->
   </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 oneoff-grey large middle">??</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 dollar large middle oneoff-grey">15</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 tiny"><a href="#">Change</a>
      <!-- react-text: 150 -->|
      <!-- /react-text --><a href="">Remove</a>
</div>
```

Basically the last div has an issue. How can I align it within the div with a border whilst keeping the other styles intact?

Also a sample [here](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/qqyxKm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your HTML needs a little tweaking - `.tiny` is currently outside `.border`.

Moving `.border` up one div will then wrap the links in the border.

Once that has been sorted, you need a `.row` around the `.tiny` div.

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbBmxN).

Updated code below:

```
<div class="cart">
    <div class="border">
        <div class="row vcenteritems itemsheight">
            <div class="col-md-8 small">
                <!-- react-text: 144 -->Docos
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 145 -->channel package
                <!-- /react-text -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 oneoff-grey large middle">??</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 dollar large middle oneoff-grey">15</div>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 tiny">
              <a href="#">Change</a>
              <!-- react-text: 150 -->|
              <!-- /react-text -->
              <a href="">Remove</a>
          </div>
       </row>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS remains the same:

```
/*************Cart******************/
.cart {

  .verticalline {
    border-left: thin solid #f7f7f7;
  }

  //todo remove this
  /**for testing**/
  .border {
    border: dashed 0.5px;
  }

  .border2 {
    border: solid red 1px;
  }

  /***fontsizes***/
  .tiny {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .small {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .costsize {
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  .medium {
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  .large {
    font-size: 40px;
  }

  //shows dollarsign left top
  .dollar:before {
    content: '$';
    font-size: 18px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  /****alignment***/
  .right {
    text-align: right;
  }

  .vcenteritems {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .hcenteritems {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .middle {
    text-align: center;
  }

  //order button collapse
  .collapse {
    display: none
  }

  .collapse.in {
    display: block
  }

  /***Heights****/
  .toplineheight {
    height: 84px;
  }

  .headerheight {
    height: 66px;
  }

  .itemsheight {
    height: 80px;
  }

  .totalheight {
    height: 107px;
  }

  .costheight {
    height: 95px;
  }

  .btn {
    height: 43px;
    width: 152px;
  }

  /**padding***/

  //
  .itemspad {
    margin-top: 8px;
   // padding: 2px;
  }

  /**colors***/
  .light-grey {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    //height:100%;
  }

  .oneoff-grey {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    height:100%;
  }

  .normal-grey {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
  }

  .rightwhite
  {
    border-right: white 2px;
  }

  .totalblue{
    background-color: #6fb9ef;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }

  .pricesblue{
    background-color: #dde8f7;
    height:100%;
  }

}
```